# transpose and merge data in pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, pivot-table, transpose

I would like to transpose some data in order to see the format shown by "table", but having the possibility to analyze the 10,20,50 columns, with sum, value_counts (), etc., instead it gives an error

```
raw_data = {'product': [10,20,50],
'key1': [1,2,3],
'key2': [51,52,53],
'tick': [1,1,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['product','key1','key2','tick'])

table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=('key1','key2'),values=('tick'), columns=('product'))

table.reset_index(inplace=True)
table['10'].sum()
'''
```

Comment: `table[10].sum()` ? the column is an integer not a string

Comment: the 10 is an integer, not a string, you should do table[10].sum()